# Too many key parts specified; max 1 parts allowed cassandra engine and mariadb

Tags: mysql, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to implement cassandra SE and MariaDB interoperability. In `cqlsh`, I'm able to create table with composite keys. When I try the same in mariadb, I'm getting error `ERROR 1070 (42000): Too many key parts specified; max 1 parts allowed`.
Here is my code which I used in `cqlsh`:

```
cqlsh:mariadbtest> create table test (test1 int, test2 bigint, test3 varchar, primary key (test1, test2)) with compact STORAGE;
```

In `Mariadb` :

```
MariaDB [test]> set global cassandra_default_thrift_host='localhost';

MariaDB [test]> create table random (test1 int(5), test2 bigint(5), test3 varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (test1, test2)) engine=cassandra keyspace='historian' thrift_host='localhost' column_family='test';
ERROR 1070 (42000): Too many key parts specified; max 1 parts allowed
```

When I use single column as my primary key, it works fine with no errors. Please help me on how to solve composite keys issue. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the storage engine. According to the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/cassandra-storage-engine-overview/#cassandras-rowkey):

> Note: Multi-column primary keys are currently not supported. Support may be added in a future version, depending on whether there is a demand for it.

It is unclear whether you would be able to define a composite partition key (i.e. `PRIMARY KEY ((test1, test2))`). I'm also not certain that would even suit your needs. It sounds like you should declare your interest if that's what you need.

Comment: I tried composite partition key and I'm getting the same error. Yes, I need it for my table. Can you please provide me an example on how to use composite key on cassandra SE and MySQL.